# UFW - Rules by Service Name Versus Port and Protocol

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, ufw

What is the difference between creating allow/deny rules via a service versus a port and protocol?

For example: `ufw allow ssh` versus `ufw allow 22/tcp` or even, `ufw allow ssh/tcp`.

Which is the 1) cleanest 2) most restrictive 3) best way to approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `ufw allow ssh`

This inserts rules that allow udp and tcp packets destined for port 22.

> `ufw allow 22/tcp`

This inserts rules that allow just tcp packets destined for port 22

> `ufw allow ssh/tcp`

This inserts rules that allow just tcp packets destined for port 22

When you provide the name of a service rather than a port number ufw looks the name up in `/etc/services` and reads the port number from it. Ultimately

```
ufw allow ssh/tcp
```

gets translated into `... 22/tcp` and from there to iptables/netfilter.

The most restrictive are the ones that limit to service/protocol (obviously you can further restrict using source address(es) etc).

As to which is cleanest/best ... that's up to you some people will prefer service names and others port numbers.